# A very basic php query related to string concatenation and sum

Tags: php, string-concatenation

```
<?php
$number1 = 1;
$number2 = 2;

echo $number1.' + ' . $number2. ' = '.$number1+$number2;
?>
```

See the above program. It is giving output as 3. Why not it is giving output as: 
1 + 2 = 3

Answer (score 2):

`+` and `.` have the *same precedence*.

```
echo $number1.' + ' . $number2. ' = '.($number1+$number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The operations are applied in order. I.e:

```
echo $number1.' + ' . $number2. ' = '.$number1+$number2;
```

Becomes:

```
echo '1 + 2 = '.$number1+$number2;
```

Becomes:

```
echo '1 + 2 = 1'+$number2;
```

Since this is addition PHP will convert the string to an int which gives `1`.
So the final expression is:

```
echo 1 + 2;//Prints 3
```

You can indicate which operations to perform together using brackets:

```
echo $number1.' + ' . $number2. ' = '.($number1+$number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

your desired output :-

```
    <?php
   $number1 = 1;
   $number2 = 2;
   echo $number1.'+ ' . $number2.'='.($number1+$number2);
   ?>
```